# NEST (2.x) Date Histogram Aggregation with fractional interval values

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am using NEST (2.3.3) object initializer syntax for creating Date Histogram Aggregation. How can I specify the Fractional values for the Interval?

```
DateHistogramAggregation dateHistogram = 
    new DateHistogramAggregation("dateHistogram")
    {
        Field = "TimestampFieldName",   
        Interval = DateInterval.Hour
    }
```

In the above data histogram aggregation I want to specify for example 1.5 hours. Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Interval` is a `Union<DateInterval, Time>` which means that it can take either a `DateInterval` enum value or a `Time` instance. Additionally, a string has an implicit conversion to an instance of `Time`. Putting these together, to set an interval of 1.5 hours would be

```
DateHistogramAggregation dateHistogram =
    new DateHistogramAggregation("dateHistogram")
    {
        Field = "TimestampFieldName",
        Interval = new Time("1.5h")
    };
```

In this case, we can't take advantage of the implicit conversion from `string` to `Time` (and then `Time` to `Union<DateInterval,Time>`) because there is no implicit conversion from string to `Union<DateInterval, Time>`. In this case, we can just use the `Time` constructor and pass it a string value for 1.5 hours, and assign this instance of `Time` to the interval.